# "Bad owner or permissions" error using Cygwin's ssh.exe

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I'm trying to use ssh.exe in Cygwin (in Windows 7). I copied a `config` file into `c:\cygwin\home\[USERNAME]\.ssh`. When I run `ssh` (for example, `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org`) I get the following error:

> OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
>   Bad owner or permissions on /home/[USERNAME]/.ssh/config

How do I get `ssh` to read my configuration file?

Comment: This issue can be repro if you move a cygwin folder from a Windows installatino to another. Especially tricky when you reinstall a computer and the computer name\username is the same to detect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the permissions of the `config` file using Cygwin's `ls` command:

```
> c:\cygwin\bin\ls.exe -la c:\cygwin\home\[USERNAME]\.ssh
```

It will probably be something like this:

```
total 5
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 Administrators None  0 Oct 20 17:02 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 [USERNAME]     None  0 Oct 19 08:15 ..
-rw-------  1 Administrators None 57 Oct 20 16:58 config
```

The config file needs to belong to [USERNAME]. Try this:

```
> c:\cygwin\bin\chown.exe [USERNAME] c:\cygwin\home\[USERNAME]\.ssh\config
```

`ls -la` should now show the correct owner. If that still doesn't work, try resetting the mode (permissions):

```
> c:\cygwin\bin\chmod.exe 700 c:\cygwin\home\[USERNAME]\.ssh\config
```

Answer (score 47):

After doing as above, I always got this:

```
total 22
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 jl None    0 Sep  9 18:44 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 jl None    0 Sep  9 18:44 ..
-rw-rw----  1 jl None  129 Jul  1 14:30 config
```

and the error on `.ssh/config`. So I've run `chown` on the `.ssh` folder, and `chmod` again like this:

```
> chown -R [USERNAME]:users .ssh/
```

and then:

```
> chmod -R 600 .ssh/
```

and finally I got it working:

```
total 29
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 jl None     0 Sep  9 18:44 .
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 jl None     0 Sep  9 18:44 ..
drw-------+ 1 jl Users    0 Sep  9 18:44 .ssh
```

**Edit(for bash on Windows10)**

When you get the error..

> Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/PATH_TO_HOME/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts).

Make sure that known_hosts is writable

> $ chmod 755 known_hosts

Note: I believe you only need to set 600 for your private key

Then, try to ssh.

When you get..

> Permanently added 'HOST_IP' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

You may replace mode 600

> $ chmod 600 known_hosts

**P.S.**: I think this is a bug on Windows 8.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks!

Comment: Also, this is quite a weird bug. On my computer (W8.1), editing the .ssh/config file in Vim always leads to this bug. It's extremely annoying, as every change to my ssh config requires running these commands.

Comment: And just to add to the weirdness, if you're using an non English version of Windows then make sure to use the locale translation of "users" when issuing this command. For example in Dutch it becomes "chown -R :Gebruikers .ssh"

Comment: For me, this worked:

chown -R m0j0:Users .ssh && chmod -R go-rwx .ssh

Comment: Tried changing the group on just .ssh/config, but it didn't work until I first changed the group on the .ssh directory itself.  Thanks!

Comment: Have a look in /etc/group if you're unsure about the exact (localized) group name.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me as well, in German you need to use `chown -R [Username]:Benutzer .ssh/`

Comment: It's not just windows 8. It happened for me (win7) after modifying the config file using my sublimeText editor, which apparently saves the file using its own permissions. The above solution fixed the problem

Answer (score 23):

This answer is copied verbatim from https://superuser.com/a/875934/82032.  This is the only answer that worked for me after a recent cygwin upgrade.

**Don't forget the ACLs**

Nothing worked for me until I stripped the file of [ACLs](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#getfacl) and reset the permissions.

```
#remove ACLs
setfacl -b ~/.ssh/config

#reset permissions
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/config
```

You can use `getfacl` to view the current ACL on a file.

```
getfacl ~/.ssh/config
```

Before I removed the ACLs (Broken):

```
# owner: Administrators
# group: None
user::rw-
group::---
group:Authenticated Users:rwx
group:SYSTEM:rwx
mask:rwx
other:---
```

After: (working)

```
# file: config
# owner: myusername
# group: None
user::rw-
group::---
other:---
```

Comment: This is what I had to do after upgrading cygwin

Comment: This requires cygwin 1.7.34-6

Comment: This is what worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

### For unix & OSX

Quite simply:

```
chown -R $USER:users ~/.ssh/
chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/
```

### For Windows

*If the file is a windows (NTFS) symbolic link, the above won't work. You need to make it a regular file. I am not sure why.*

If you don't have openssh or cygwin, use chocolatey to install it easily.

```
choco install cyg-get
```

**Open Cygwin Terminal** that was installed with chocolatey and run (note that `ssh-keygen` creates new keys):

```
cyg-get install openssh
ssh-keygen
cd ~/.ssh && explorer.exe .
```

Verify keys are there (or replace them with the keys you want), and then in Cygwin shell:

```
chown -R $USER:users ~/.ssh/
chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/
```

Or for the rare case that you're using (and generated the keys from) **chocolatey's SSH** package:

```
chown -R $USER:users  /cygdrive/c/Users/$USER/.ssh
chmod -R 600 /cygdrive/c/Users/$USER/.ssh
```

Comment: This is usually it for me, since the group is usually wrong on the files.

Answer (score 3):

Important note if your Windows is not in US English: the "users" group's name is locale-dependant. For example, if your Windows is in Spanish, you'll have to change the files' ownership with `chown $USER:Usuarios *`

Answer (score 1):

None of these (chmod/chown/icacls/setacl/copyacls/explorer>security) worked on my cygwin64/win7/admin, finally this works with `cygwin64/ssh -F ~/.ssh/config` other solutions are to use older ssh in cygwin32 or ssh in git for windows..

Comment: Using `-F` will solve the problem with `config`, but won't solve permissions for private keys.

Answer (score 1):

For those who uses `noacl` in path with `~/.ssh` dir simple solution is to create native NTFS symbolic link:

```
cmd# mklink c:\home\.ssh c:\opt\cygwin\home\misc\.ssh
symbolic link created for c:\home\.ssh <<===>> c:\opt\cygwin\home\misc\.ssh
```

With `noacl` there is no way to set permissions other then `rwxr-xr-x` or `rw-r--r--`. As `/` hierarchy should be without `noacl` (or should be with `acl`) you can create directory here and point to it problematic places for Cygwin's apps.

Comment: Given this is a directory, the simple solution would be using a junction, because that doesn't require the privileges required for setting a symbolic link. That'd be `mklink /j` then or the `junction` tool from the Sysinternals Suite.

Answer (score 0):

***tldr:*** You may have created the config as adminstrator

### Solution

These solutions may be overkill if you ended up mistakenly creating the file as admin, and trying to use the file with local perms.

- Copy the contents of your ssh config
- Delete the file
- Open a new shell (local - non admin)
- Navigate to the path where your config is stored (*usually `~/.ssh` in PowerShell or `%userprofile%\.ssh` in cmd*)
- Run `notepad .\config`

---

### Simple commands (PowerShell):

```
$sshPath = '~/.ssh/config'
$content = cat $sshPath
# In case the line above fails, this check will prevent your current config to get deleted
if ($content) {
  rm $sshPath
  $content | Out-File -en ascii $sshPath
}
```