# cygwin's chmod behaves as working, but it does not work

Tags: windows-7, bash, permissions, cygwin, chmod

My Cygwin installation is behaving strangely: `chmod` does not work.

```
[09:45 Administrator@DellIns14 ~] > ls -ls /usr/bin/chmod
64K -rwxr-xr-x 1 Administrator None 38K Feb  6  2012 /usr/bin/chmod

[09:47 Administrator@DellIns14 ~] > rm /tmp/example.sh
rm: remove regular empty file `/tmp/example.sh'? y
[09:48 Administrator@DellIns14 ~] > touch /tmp/example.sh
[09:48 Administrator@DellIns14 ~] > ls -ls /tmp/example.sh
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 Administrator None 0 Jul  8 09:48 /tmp/example.sh
[09:48 Administrator@DellIns14 ~] > chmod -v +x /tmp/example.sh
mode of `/tmp/example.sh' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
[09:48 Administrator@DellIns14 ~] > ls -ls /tmp/example.sh
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 Administrator None 0 Jul  8 09:48 /tmp/example.sh
[09:48 Administrator@DellIns14 ~] >
```

Note that the directory is writable, as the file is created.

When I look at this directory from a *windows* perspective, it is reported as **read-only** (even after I change it to read-write, it reverts to read-only). 
Screen-captures are at [cygwin's /tmp is read-only in windows, and cannot be changed to read-write](https://www.diigo.com/item/p/oooepprzcbsredsaczbecarosa)

Can you suggest how to debug/solve?

Environment:
Windows 7, Cygwin 1.7.29(0.272/5/3) i686

Comment: Same problem for ~/.ssh/config on win7+cygwin64, (ssh won't run unless I can chmod 0600 config) and NONE of the answers below help (/etc/fstab, setfacl, subinacl /file config /display).

Comment: @boardrider : The link to your screen capture gives error 404. Do you mean that you can't change the file to writable even on the Windows command line, or using Windows Explorer?

Comment: @boardrider: What happens if you set the permissions with `setfacl`? See _man setfacl_. Perhaps [this](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html) article is also useful.

Comment: Sorry, @user1934428, this is a thread from more than seven years ago: I don't remember.

Answer (score 9):

Kudos to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730041/updating-file-permissions-with-git-bash-on-windows-7 contents pasted below

---

You are probably using NTFS or FAT32 on Windows, and those filesystems do not support the *executable* permission. Instead, [cygwin looks at the file name and contents to determine whether it's executable](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-filemodes.html):

> Files are considered to be executable if the filename ends with .bat, .com or .exe, or if its content starts with #!.

So you should make sure that the bash file starts with a shebang. Then, you should be able to just execute the file, disregarding the permission output of `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

I found  [This Answer](https://superuser.com/a/875934/419295) helpful.

Besides normal POSIX permissions that contoll owner, group, other access, the file permission in Cygwin may also be affected by Windows ACL.

In your case, please try

```
ls -l /tmp/example.sh
getfacl /tmp/example.sh
setfacl -b /tmp/example.sh
ls -l /tmp/example.sh
chmod -v +x /tmp/example.sh
ls -l /tmp/example.sh
```

Comment: If you found additional permission by getfacl, you make need to check/reset /tmp too.

Comment: Thanks @Danny Zeng: I'll keep the [gs]etfacl commands in mind. As for the original problem - seems that in the meantime, it vanished, and now chmod works as expected on my cygwin. Quite a few things were changed on my system in the interim, so I cannot hazard a guess what was the change that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to chmod until I found that /etc/fstab contained:

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,noacl,posix=0,user 0 0
```

but needed to be:

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

After closing all open Cygwin processes and restarting, all worked.

Comment: Thanks @rshdev, but on my machine, the `noacl` is already absent, viz: 
$ tail -1 /etc/fstab
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0

Answer (score 2):

Just add `#!/bin/bash` in the first line of the script,

but **it is important** to do it with **nano** or **vi** .

After saving - the file will showed as green, with executable permission.

see image for example :

[image]

Comment: How does it answer the question on the top?

Comment: I edited it now, and give a detailed explain how adding this line.

Answer (score 0):

Chmod does not work (silently) on my computer if the paths are in Windows format.
With "cygdrive" paths it works. Here is the example:

```
D:\>mkdir D:\test

D:\>touch D:\test\qwe

D:\>ls -l D:\test\qwe
-rw-r--r-- 1 cat None 0 Sep 16 10:40 'D:\test\qwe'

D:\>cacls D:\test\qwe
D:\test\qwe Все:(ID)F

D:\>chmod 600 D:\test\qwe

D:\>ls -l D:\test\qwe
-rw-r--r-- 1 cat None 0 Sep 16 10:40 'D:\test\qwe'

D:\>cacls D:\test\qwe
D:\test\qwe Все:(ID)F

D:\>chmod 600 /cygdrive/D/test/qwe

D:\>ls -l D:\test\qwe
-rw-r--r-- 1 cat None 0 Sep 16 10:40 'D:\test\qwe'

D:\>cacls D:\test\qwe
D:\test\qwe CAT\cat:(специальный доступ:)
                STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL
                DELETE
                READ_CONTROL
                WRITE_DAC
                WRITE_OWNER
                SYNCHRONIZE
                STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED
                FILE_GENERIC_READ
                FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
                FILE_READ_DATA
                FILE_WRITE_DATA
                FILE_APPEND_DATA
                FILE_READ_EA
                FILE_WRITE_EA
                FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

        CAT\None:(специальный доступ:)
                 READ_CONTROL
                 SYNCHRONIZE
                 FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES

        Все:(специальный доступ:)
            READ_CONTROL
            SYNCHRONIZE
            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
```

Also there is an oddity in `ls -l` behaviour. Native Windows `cacls` confirms that second `chmod 600` was successful, but `ls -l` says `-rw-r--r--` even after that.

So I've used cmd "function" for convert windows-paths to cygdrive-paths:

```
call :chmod "D:\test\qwe"
rem ...
goto :eof

:chmod
set "STMP=%~dp1"
set "STMP=%STMP:\=/%"
set "STMP=%STMP::=%"
set "STMP=/cygdrive/%STMP%%~nx1"
chmod 600 "%STMP%"
set "STMP="
goto :eof
```

My configuration: Windows 7, cygwin x64 updated at September 2020, NTFS.