# openssh windows bad owner or permissions

Tags: windows, ssh, file-permissions

I've installed openssh for windows and when I run `ssh localhost` I get

> Bad owner or permissions on C:\Users\gary/.ssh/config

I've looked at these 2 questions ["Bad owner or permissions" error using Cygwin's ssh.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/348694/bad-owner-or-permissions-error-using-cygwins-ssh-exe) and https://serverfault.com/questions/253313/ssh-returns-bad-owner-or-permissions-on-ssh-config but none of the answers work for me.  sshd is running as a service as the Local System user.  I've run `chmod 0600 C:\Users\gary\.ssh\config` and `chown gary C:\Users\gary\.ssh\config`.  I've also cleared the ACL by running `setfacl -b C:\Users\gary\.ssh\config` and then `chmod 0600 C:\Users\gary\.ssh\config` again.  I've also tried changing the owner to SYSTEM and got the same error.

I'm not sure what else to do, is there anything wrong with my setup?  I also have git installed which installed mingw, I deleted ssh and sshd from my git installation so they wouldn't be on my path.

Other commands I've run are
`icacls "C:\Users\gary\.ssh\config" /setowner gary`
`chown -R gary:1049089 C:\Users\gary\.ssh`

`ls -la C:\Users\gary\.ssh\config` shows

> -rw-r--r-- 1 gary 1049089 229 Jan  3 14:43 'C:\Users\gary.ssh\config'

it keeps showing this even after changing the owner to SYSTEM, but in the file properties in file explorer it shows SYSTEM as the owner

Comment: I had the same problem and doing what is described here fixed it: https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows SSH: Permissions for 'private-key' are too open](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open)

Answer (score 0):

I set the owner and permissions of `C:\Users\<me>\.ssh` (and all child objects, including `config`) to `<me>` (and removed all previous permissions, in my case it was `SYSTEM`, `Administrators` and some other stuff), and it worked!

So it needs to be ***just*** **`<your-username>`**.

But then I encountered another error which was that it didn't recognize any of my existing keys, which were created with RSA. Currently it only understand [Ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Ed25519) which you can test by running `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and it'll give you an error saying "unknown key type rsa". There's an [open issue on github](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/973).